# Getting an error in my Developer Console on one of my Go Launcher Themes

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception

This seems to only happen on my free themes. none of my paid themes seem to ever have any errors. Any idea why this error is happening?

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Source method PathClassLoader.findClass()

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{slcmotor.goex.gloss/slcmotor.goex.gloss}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slcmotor.goex.gloss in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/slcmotor.goex.gloss-2.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1742)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slcmotor.goex.gloss in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/slcmotor.goex.gloss-2.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1733)
... 11 more
```

Also this one

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

BaseDexClassLoader.findClass()

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{slcmotor.goex.gloss/slcmotor.goex.gloss}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slcmotor.goex.gloss
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slcmotor.goex.gloss
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1883)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the class "slcmotor.goex.gloss", which seems to be related to the Black Gloss Go Launcher Theme http://appaware.com/app/black-gloss-go-launcher-theme/slcmotor.goex.gloss. Did this theme ever work for you? If it didn't the classnames in the free theme might have been wrong or the theme got corrupted somehow

Comment: Well when installing on my device it works just fine. Also its installed on 86 active devices in the market and this is the only errors. its not like i have a lot of users reporting errors, just these couple.